# Jython support in editors?

Tags: editor, jython

I've recently started writing some performance tests in [The Grinder 3](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/#What+is+The+Grinder%3F), and one of the first things I noticed is that PyCheckMate doesn't work because it can't find some of the imports. Which editor(s) provide the best support for Jython?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As David Mentioned Pydev and even though it is a well developed piece of software I can't stand eclipse. Thankfully there are other choices. The latest version of Netbeans has jython / python [www.netbeans.org](https://netbeans.apache.org/) and Komodo from activestate either the [IDE](https://www.activestate.com/blog/activestate-komodo-ide-now-open-source/) or the free [komodo edit](https://web.archive.org/web/20100418065155/http://www.activestate.com:80/komodo_edit/)

and pretty much any editor that supports python will give you some level of support for it but as far as a IDE built and designed for Jython... I think netbeans comes the closest otherwise the only reason to use the bloated behemoth called eclipse is because of pydev.

Answer (score 5):

As a long-time fan of the [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) IDE, I've used the [Pydev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) plugin when working with Python and Jython projects.

You get code completion, syntax highlighting, refactoring, outline view, debugging tools, and all the other features you'd expect out of a top-notch editor.

Comment: Is there a way to use it on individual files that aren't necessarily part of a PyDev project? Creating a new Eclipse project for a 1-module script is a bit overkill.

Comment: @HankGay Did you find an answer to this by any chance?

Comment: @johnny No, we wound up not using Grinder 3, so I no longer needed it. IntelliJ is supposed to have pretty good support, from what I've heard, but I haven't gone to check lately.

Answer (score 1):

Tried a bunch of tools now. Great solution for all y'all out there (especially the ones who don't like eclipse - me included!): IntelliJ IDEA 14+ Community Edition + Python Plugin. It gives you code completion, syntax highlighting etc. for Jython, means you write nice Python syntax and get code completion for third party stuff like Sikuli - check this [example](https://github.com/Tset-Noitamotua/Sikuli-and-Robot-Framework-Integration/issues/4).

Answer (score 1):

You might also check out [TigerJython](http://jython.tobiaskohn.ch/) and [JythonMusic](https://jythonmusic.me/). Both support pure Jython (i.e., Python syntax + access to all Java APIs), but also have extra libraries.